# How to build a splash screen in Kivy with (or without) ScreenManager that switches automatically to the next Screen?

Tags: python, kivy, splash-screen

I'm trying to create a "SplashScreen" with python and kivy. The idea is to start the program, show the SplashScreen as fast as possible, run some methods in background, then automatically switch to the "MainScreen". Thats the first moment where user input is possible and expected.

The problem is, that every way I tried, I got following result: Program starts running, shows a blank white window, runs my methods, shows the SplashScreen, immediately switches to MainScreen.

I simply don't get how to force kivy show the SplashScreen before running the methods I want. To clearify that: "SplashScreen" does not mean anthing fancy like transparency or stuff. Just another standard screen.

**Here is my Code:**

mainWindow.py

```
Builder.load_file("loadingscreen.kv")
Builder.load_file("mainscreen.kv")

class LoadingScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class FaitApp(App):

    LoadingStartUp = None

    def build(self):
        self.root = ScreenManager()
        self.root.add_widget(LoadingScreen(name='LoadingScreen'))
        self.root.add_widget(MainScreen(name='MainScreen'))
        return self.root

    def on_start(self):
        self.LoadingStartUp = LoadingStartUp(self)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.LoadingStartUp.loadButtonImages,0)
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = FaitApp()
    app.run()
    sys.exit()
```

loadingscreen.kv

```
#kivy 1.10.1
    <LoadingScreen>:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1 , 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
        Label:
            font_size: 42
            text: root.name
```

mainscreen.kv

```
#kivy 1.10.1
    <MainScreen>:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1 , 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
        Label:
            font_size: 42
            text: root.name
```

loadingStartUp.py

```
class LoadingStartUp(object):

    app = None

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        return

    def loadButtonImages(self):
        log.debug('LoadingStartUp')
        log.debug('Waiting for everything ready!')
        sleep(5)
        self.app.root.current = 'MainScreen'
        return
```

I also tried to use `Clock.schedule_once()` within `build()` and `on_start()`. I even tried to load the sites without ScreenManager with `self.root = Builder.load_file()`. The result was the same every time as described above.

It would be enought I think to detect when the SplashScreen is correctly shown on screen and run a method after that.

Any solutions/hints/tipps/advices are very appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What's your target platform? On android / iOS you have an option to include a splash image when packaging your app so you wouldn't need to do this manually

Comment: Platform is Windows at first. But the idea is to get it to work on Android, Linux, and eventually on IOS as well. So I have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get what you want by eliminating the `sleep(5)` from the `loadButtonImages()` method and modify the `Clock.schedule_once(self.LoadingStartUp.loadButtonImages,0)` call to `Clock.schedule_once(self.LoadingStartUp.loadButtonImages,5)`. The `sleep()` call prevents the GUI from doing anything during those 5 seconds. And the `5` in the `Clock.schedule_once()` call prevents the main screen from showing for 5 seconds.

Comment: I'll try that today.
The sleep(5) is just there to "simulate" doing stuff for 5 seconds (loading images, getting settings from ini file etc.). Perhaps I should replace that with a loop that returns after about 5 seconds.
But when there is stuff going on in loadButtonImages(), and it takes a while to finish, will that not also prevent the kivy main loop from running? And as far as I understand that means, that the LoadingScreen won't be loaded this or that way.

Comment: Anything that you do on the main thread (which is the GUI thread) will stop the GUI (and that includes calls to `sleep`). If you need other work to be done, you should do it in another thread, and trigger the changes to the GUI using `Clock.schedule_once()`.

Comment: Thats why I tried to `Clock.schedule_once()` earlier. But with the `sleep(5)` within the Clock, it blocked the mainthread too.
So the result was the same: Startup, withe window, 5 seconds 'till the `sleep(5)` is done, LoadingScreen, instant Switch to MainScreen.

Comment: The call to `Clock.schedule_once(self.LoadingStartUp.loadButtonImages,5)` will not block the main thread.